# Problems with Fluid Simulation baking / cache

Tags: baking, fluid-simulation

Recently today, I created a fluid simulation.  I baked through it a few times, updating the settings to get to what I wanted.  I reached a desirable effect.

Then the fluid simulation baking stopped working.  The bake itself would hardly take any time at all.  When I play through the simulation, the mesh switches between its original state as a fluid domain and the first frame of the simulation.

I've researched the question but haven't found any problems that looked like this.

Here is what the simulation like, played in the viewer:
[image: Fluid simulation switching rapidly between states.]

Here are the settings of the fluid domain and the inflow:
[image: Domain settings.]
[image: Inflow settings.]

I'm not the most experienced in Blender fluid simulations and hardly have a lead to why this is happening.

Thank you, in advance, for your time!